# Schema.org Character's URL for a PerformanceRole's entry

Tags: schema.org

From Schema.org [`PerformanceRole`](https://schema.org/PerformanceRole) JSON-LD example:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Movie",
  "name": "Ghostbusters",
  "sameAs": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostbusters",
  "actor": {
    "@type": "PerformanceRole",
    "actor": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": "Bill Murray"
    },
    "characterName": "Dr. Peter Venkman"
  }
}
</script>
```

I can add a `sameAs` for each `Person` and thus have a reference/profile URL for each actor/actress involved with the movie.

Could I have the same for the Character performed by the actors?

In the example above Dr. Peter Venkman could have a link to [something like this](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087332/characters/nm0000195), a page with information specifically about that Character, regardless of the actor/actress interpreting him.

But, as far as I know, the `characterName` Property only accepts raw text.

Comment: Maybe adding the sameAs to the PerformanceRole makes sense?

Comment: It does, but very little IMHO. Guess I'll stick with `character`, another Property from CreativeWork like `actor`. It's awful having to repeat the code block but it fits better, I think.

Comment: here is approach that will work but looks convoluted: `Movie/mainEntityOfPage/Report` where the `@ID` for Report is reused, for example, for `@Person/Actor` who played `@Report/Hamlet`. If the approach is acceptable, ping-back and i'll write it up.

Comment: It would be indeed very confusing — and in my case, even more, given Hugo's weird syntax — Also, even though in my case there is the main character, of course, all of them are more or less of the same importance, so I think it wouldn't be right to assume with `mainEntityOfPage`. However, if you don't mind, it would be interesting if you could post, especially because it's very difficult to find these specific use-cases. I'll post my own solution based on the `character` Property as well.